# 2.9.2 CP Session Timeout - Is there no solution?

Tags: control-panel

I’ve found many threads both here and elsewhere on session timeout in the CP, however I’ve yet to see a solution that works.

One of my clients is complaining that the timeout is too short, and so far I haven’t been able to extend (preferably indefinitely) it.

I’ve also tried with both session and cookies, session only, cookies only.

Any help with this issue on 2.9.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, have you tried the terrible idea of modifying core files? In 2.9.2 you can try modifying system/expressionengine/libraries/Session.php and edit line 74:

```
public $cpan_session_len    = 3600;  // Admin sessions expire in one hour
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the session time variable may have been deprecated in recent EE updates, since it is no longer listed in the EE knowledge base for config variables:

```
$config['cp_session_ttl'] = 'insert number value here';
```

Default is/was 3600 seconds for that value.

Have you tried as an alternative setting the cp_session_type variable in your config.php:

```
$config['cp_session_type'] = 'c';
```

When set to cookies only (value of c), rather than using sessions (s or cs for sessions + cookies), you should then see an option on the cpanel screen next time you login to 'Auto login on future visits?'

the login will remain valid for up to 2 weeks I believe, so even on closing the CPanel, navigating back to the page later should log back in automagically.

Not a direct answer I know, but hope it helps.